# Iterating over nested objects in Stylus

Tags: javascript, css, json, node.js, stylus

I have a build script that complies my stylus and passes some data in.

```
stylus(stylFile)
  .set('filename', 'index.css')
  .define('data', require('./data.json'))
  .render(...)
```

The data.json file contains an object of groups, and each group is composed of more objects that represent items.

```
{
  "group1": {
    "item1": {
      "width": 1
    },
    "item2": {
      "width": 2
    }
  },
  "group2": {
    "item3": {
      "width": 3
    }
  }
}
```

In my Stylus file I want to iterate through the groups, and then through their items like so

```
for group, items in data
  #{group}
    for id, item in items
      #{id}
        width item.width
```

I would expect the output of this to be

```
#group1 #item1 {
  width: 1;
}
#group1 #item2 {
  width: 2;
}
#group2 #item3 {
  width: 3;
}
```

Instead I get

```
ParseError: index.css:118:1
   114|   #{group}
   115|     for id, item in items
   116|       #{id}
   117|         width item.width
   118| 
--------^

expected "indent", got "outdent"
```

Comment: I have a feeling that this has something to do with Stylus' built in "hashes" which my data must get coerced into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how you get the `json` in stylus but with *hash objects* you can do this:

**STYLUS**

```
data={
  "group1": {
    "item1": {
      "width": 1
    },
    "item2": {
      "width": 2
    }
  },
  "group2": {
    "item3": {
      "width": 3
    }
  }
}

for group in data
  #{group}
    items = data[group]
    for item in items
      #{item}
        for property, value in items[item]
          {property} value
```

**OUTPUT**

```
#group1 #item1 {
  width: 1;
}
#group1 #item2 {
  width: 2;
}
#group2 #item3 {
  width: 3;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

You can get the `json` from stylus file and convert in *hash object*:

```
data = json('data.json', { hash: true })

for group in data
  #{group}
    items = data[group]
    for item in items
      #{item}
        for property, value in items[item]
          {property} value
```

Comment: I get the json into stylus using the `define()` function in my build script. So NPM opens the JSON, turns it into a JS object, then hands that to Stylus which I presume coerces it into a hash.

Comment: Sorry, but your solution doesn't work for me when using data from JSON. I get `#id # {
  (null): 0;
}` repeated for each item.